# Poner texto en una parte especifica de un archivo de texto en consola JAVA

Tags: java

Me gustaría poder poner la palabra "teléfono" justo antes de los números, ¿Existe algún tipo de comando que detecte los números y que justo me coloque el texto ahí? ¿o simplemente me ponga la palabra "teléfono" donde quiero? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    public void leerDirectorio() throws IOException{


    try {
       FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:/Users/Migui/Desktop/directorio.txt");
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

       String cadena;
       int numeropersonas = 0;
       while((cadena=br.readLine())!=null){
           System.out.println("Nombre: "+ cadena + "Telefono");


           ++numeropersonas;

       }
    System.out.println("Hay " + numeropersonas + " personas en la lista");


    br.close();


    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("No se ha encontrado texto");
    }



}
```

Comment: Si utilizas `split`como sugiere @itsvan, te aconsejo que almacenes los datos separados por un delimitador tipo guión(`-`), coma (`,`), punto y coma (`;`) o similares para poder identificar la posición del `array` de forma correcta, ya que si añades nombres compuestos o apellidos, no funcionará correctamente con espacios.

Answer (score 0):

La función split() se puede utilizar no solo para un carácter si no para varios.

```
String[] palabrasSeparadas = cadena.split(" ");
```

y de esta forma tendras los dos datos y haces esto.

```
System.out.println("Nombre: "+ palabrasSeparadas[0] + "Telefono"+palabrasSeparadas[1] );
```

Comment: En este caso, tendría un problema si utiliza `split` y en la cadena hay nombres compuestos como, por ejemplo, Miguel Ángel, o dos apellidos.

Comment: Tienes razon, no visualice que los nombres tenian apellidos. Dado a que por lo que se ve solo es un apellido seria asi:       `System.out.println("Nombre: "+ palabrasSeparadas[0] +  palabrasSeparadas[1]+ "Telefono"+palabrasSeparadas[2] ); `     Si siempre es nombre y apellido y el numero utiliza esto y de otra forma solo adapta el array pero esto es una posible solucion sencilla y util

Answer (score 0):

Este metodo te servirá para lo que necesitas:

```
 public static void main(String... args){
    String[] st = splitNumeroLetras("Manuel Perez 1318238");
    //El número de cédula está en el índice 0, los nombres en el índice 1
    System.out.println("Nombre: "+st[1]+" , Telefono: "+st[0] );
}

private static String[] splitNumeroLetras(String s) {
    OptionalInt indicePrimerNumero= IntStream.range(0, s.length())
            .filter(i -> Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
            .findFirst();

    String letras = s;
    String numeros = "";

    if(indicePrimerNumero.isPresent()) {
        letras = s.substring(0, indicePrimerNumero.getAsInt());
        numeros = s.substring(indicePrimerNumero.getAsInt());
    }

    return new String[] {numeros, letras};
}
```

Esto imprime:

> Nombre: Manuel Perez  , Telefono: 1318238

Debes tener java 8 para utilizar la clase OptionalInt

Espero que te sirva.